# Installed Eclipse on Mint 19.3 Xfce, text editors keep flashing

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

Downloaded and installed the latest [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org) package, but every time I open any file to edit, the editor view keeps flashing. I've reset the Appearance settings to defaults, but makes no difference. This is my setup, and it doesn't use any proprietary drivers:

```
System:    Host: hostname Kernel: 4.15.0-91-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.1 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 80C1 v: 96.31 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.11 date: 07/23/2015 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 36.7 Wh condition: 36.7/41.6 Wh (88%) model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-5200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 17558 
           Speed: 850 MHz min/max: 500/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 932 2: 1235 3: 1084 4: 1087 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-91-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 
           bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtl8723be v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 0d:00.0 
           IF: wlp13s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 118.46 GiB (25.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050A7E680 size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 461.26 GiB used: 118.46 GiB (25.7%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: /home size: 461.26 GiB used: 118.46 GiB (25.7%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 39.5 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 260 Uptime: 2h 53m Memory: 11.64 GiB used: 2.60 GiB (22.3%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 7.5.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [a solution](https://subhadipsblog.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/how-to-fix-eclipse-ide-flickering-issue-on-debian/)  after digging around, and changing this environment variable in a script to call the executable like this worked for me:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
```